# Google Search Appliance RSS Feed Ingestion?

Tags: confluence, google-search-appliance

I am trying to determine if it is possible to configure Google Search Appliance 7.0 to index via an RSS feed URL? In this particular case, I am looking to set up a Confluence 5.1.4 RSS feed URL that is indexed via Google Search Appliance.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, you would need a custom connector or somehow have this RSS feed be converted into an HTML document that could be crawled.

Answer (score 0):

The GSA allows you to push XML feeds to it so the simplest way would probably be to write a simple proxy application that accepts an RSS feed and converts the incoming RSS to the XML feed format that the GSA accepts.
It would be pretty trivial to do this conversion using XSLT.

Otherwise, as @jeromegv suggests, write a connector that accepts HTTP requests from the GSA, fetches the RSS feed and returns it to the GSA in a format it can understand.

It's worth noting that several Google for Work Search partners have developed Confluence connectors so you could probably pick up an off the shelf product to do this that will extract relevant metadata and respect security ACLs properly.